# Spring Boot - SQS Consumer Health Check

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have built a SQS consumer using Spring Boot. This app does not listen to any http or https port. I usually use spring boot actuator for my services that listen on http ports. However for an application similar to this how can I expose a health check endpoint?

Comment: why not wrap it with a spring-boot and use actuators?

Comment: My app is already a spring boot app. But it is not listening on http port since my program is just a consumer to sqs. if I add spring boot actuator , will the health check endpoint alone be exposed on a specific http port?

Comment: A simple implementation would be to write logs to the DB for whenever your consumer processes, and then build a basic REST API that queries the DB for the latest logs.

Comment: @PunterVicky I meant add spring-web to the project and expose a http end point that monitor the consumer, the problem with listening to logs can occur when the consumer is idle, it might seems it down

Comment: Thanks @shahaf. Please post an answer and I will accept